# How I can select data from Firebase Database with data in level 3 on Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How I can select key of “`Notifications`” with value “`Show Again`” if `true`?

This is my query but it’s not working.

```
String startAtKey = "order_trinhvanminh2009@gmail,com";
//Query to get the notification in orders is allow showing.
Query queryNotification = dataNotification.orderByChild("order")
                             .startAt(true, startAtKey).endAt(true, startAtKey).orderByChild("Notifications")
                             .orderByChild("Show Again").equalTo(true);
```

Here’s my database structure:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is access child of object like this.!

```
   mdatabaseRef.child("order").child("order_trinhvanminh2009@gmail,com_12").child("Notifications").child("order_order_trinhvanminh2009@gmail,com_12_notification_0").orderByChild("Show Again").equals("true").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override     
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                     String value = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    }
```

all you have to do is nested query

```
 dataSnapshot.getChildren(); 

    mdatabaseRef.child("order").child(dataSnapshot.getChildren()).



     mdatabaseRef.child("order").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override     
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        String key = child.getKey();
         fun(key);
         }

  private void fun(String key){

    mdatabaseRef.child("order").child(key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override     
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
  String key = child.getKey();
   fun(key);
 }

    }
```

Comment: I can't because I have a lot of order_trinhvanminh2009@gmail,com_etc. That why I ask this quesion

Comment: You want to access random child and show them in list.?

Comment: No! I want to access only child has Notifications with "Show again" true. order->key of order -> notification -> key of notification -> properties "Show again" is true

Comment: Thank you so much for your idea! Have a nice day!

Comment: You can get Your result from it.! just call nested FirebaseEventListeners

Comment: I think I have to query 2 times.

Comment: @TrịnhMinh try what I'm trying to say...yes you have to query more then once(Nested Query)..

Comment: Yes, Query more than once. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, but "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: Only 14 reputations, I need one more!

Comment: I can't. It still shows "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputations are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score". This answer can't be accepted unless I have more than 15 reputations.

Comment: Yes. I did! Right?